# How to call a php code on html button click

Tags: javascript, php, python, html

i am working on a project that detects facial expressions in python.but i have to provide image to this code through php.The following php code saves image in directory.how can i call the following code in html button.

```
<?php
     function fun(){

    $img = $_POST['image'];
    $folderPath = "C:/xampp/htdocs/";

    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $img);
    $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
    $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];

    $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
    $fileName = '1'. '.jpeg';

    $file = $folderPath . $fileName;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);

    print_r($fileName);
    $command = escapeshellcmd("python C:/xampp/htdocs/generate_graph.py");
    $output = shell_exec($command);



 }
 ?>
```

Comment: There are two main methods to connect to a server from a HTML page, a form element and an AJAX call (= XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: You should be able to do this via hyperlinking this PHP script URL on that button via <a></a> tag

Answer (score 1):

HTML form should be like the blow if your **form and PHP code** are on the same page.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
#Updading based on comment 
     <button type="submit" class="">Submit</button>
</form>
```

## Remove the    `function fun(){}`

## Add the following :

```
if(isset($_POST)){

  $img = $_POST['image'];
    $folderPath = "C:/xampp/htdocs/";

    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $img);
    $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
    $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];

    $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
    $fileName = '1'. '.jpeg';

    $file = $folderPath . $fileName;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);

    print_r($fileName);
    $command = escapeshellcmd("python C:/xampp/htdocs/generate_graph.py");
    $output = shell_exec($command);
}
```

Since your action is empty then it will hit the current page and `if` condition will work because of form submitting as `POST` method.

Hope it will help.

Comment: i add button in form tag .whenever i clicks on button it do nothing.

Comment: I donot know much about php.i think i am putting this code in wrong place.I am still getting no response on button click.i am putitng the  given php code after </form>tag .is it right place?

Comment: could you please dump the whole code in your question?

Comment: it is working.I have another question.I have to run this code after every 10 seconds.How can i do that?

Comment: You've to use `javascript` for your last question.